# Vue.js - Component with two rowspan

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I'm beginner with Vue.js and I would like to use component. I have a (dynamic) table with machines (SN = serial number) and their money for each source so I want to use rowspan. Each row will be instance of component because has own checkbox and I would like to work with it later. Problem is that I don't know how to use loop with creating component which is a bit complicated inside table. Here is example:

```
<div id="container">
    <table border="1">
        <template v-for="row in storage.rows">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2"><input type="checkbox"></td>
                <td rowspan="2">{{row.sn}}</td>
                <td>{{row.source}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{row.pair.source}}</td>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#container',

        data: {
            storage: {
                rows: [
                    {sn: 111, source: 'EK', pair: {source: 'VLT', in: 100}},
                    {sn: 222, source: 'EK', pair: {source: 'VLT', in: 200}}
                ]
            }
        },


    });
</script>
```

This works fine but I don't know how to transform template to component. With Vue.js I'm using Laravel and its template engine Blade so I have workaround like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <table border="1">
        @foreach($differences as $difference)
            <tr is="ek" diff="{{ json_encode($difference) }}"></tr>
            <tr is="vlt" diff="{{ json_encode($difference->pair) }}"></tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
</div>

<template id="ek-template">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td rowspan="2">@{{ difference.sn }}</td>
        <td>@{{ difference.source }}</td>
    </tr>
</template>

<template id="source-template">
    <tr>
        <td>@{{ difference.source }}</td>
    </tr>
</template>

<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#container',

        data: {
            storage: {
                differences: {!! json_encode($differences) !!}
            }
        },

        components: {
            ek: {
                template: '#ek-template',
                props: ['diff'],

                computed: {
                    difference: function () {
                        return JSON.parse(this.diff);
                    },
                },
            },

            vlt: {
                template: '#source-template',
                props: ['diff'],
                computed: {
                    difference: function () {
                        return JSON.parse(this.diff);
                    },
                },
            }
        },
    });
</script>
```

And I want to use Vue.js loop instead Laravel's `foreach` because I have already data in Vue.js object. Is there any solution how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to mix blade and vue js templates.

Your example is correct, you just need to convert to become a VueJs component for a single file component. (the files *.vue) A vue component structure is

```
// template should only have one root (e.g. wrap in div)
<template>
    <div id="container">
        <table border="1">
            <template v-for="row in storage.rows">
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2"><input type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td rowspan="2">{{row.sn}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.source}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{row.pair.source}}</td>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    // a data has to be a function within a vue component
    data () {
        return {
            storage: {
                rows: [
                    {sn: 111, source: 'EK', pair: {source: 'VLT', in: 100}},
                    {sn: 222, source: 'EK', pair: {source: 'VLT', in: 200}}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

// styling for a template
<style>
</style>
```

A new laravel 5.3 project have a sample vue component preinstalled. You can use that as a reference and use gulp to compile all your vue components (*.vue) to a single file (e.g. app.js)